# android studio 3.4, não consigo usar celular como emulador

Tags: android-studio

Boa noite
Peço ajuda, eu instalei o android studio 3.4, eu não consigo usar o celular como emulador, a versão do meu celular é 8.1.0 samsung, ja habilitei o celular em modo de desenvolvedor, troquei o cabo USB, instalei o intel HAXM, o samsung USB, e nada, ja instalei outras versões do android studio e tbm nada, se algum puder me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: Quando passei por isso instalei os drivers USB da Samsung e deu certo.  Link para download :: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/android-usb-driver-for-windows

Comment: eu instalei também e não resolveu, mas vou tentar de novo

Comment: reinstalei o USB da samsung de novo e não adiantou, não aparece a opção do emulador via USB no android virtual device manager e alguém sabe de uma escola que de um curso sobre android perto de Jundiaí? Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: No seu SDK Manager, tal ver tenha que instalar o Google USB driver.